# EditText location doesn't update when keyboard is dismissed

Tags: android

I have an EditText on a ScrollView in an Activity that has

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

set.
I'm trying to anchor another (popup) view to that EditText, that appears if there is invalid text entered.

In order to anchor it,

```
EditView.getLocationOnScreen();
```

is called. So far, so good.

But I'm also dismissing the keyboard when the popup view appears, and if the EditText moved above the keyboard for text entry, then the EditText moves back down to the original position, but the popup appears where the EditText was (when the keyboard was showing).
If I log the location points with (getLocationOnScreen())for the EditText before and after keyboard dismiss, I can see they are the same.

My question - Is there a way to update the EditText location after the keyboard is dismissed?

If it helps, I'm using https://github.com/lupidan/PopoverView for the popup, but this to me is an issue outside of that code.

Answer (score 2):

A better option than using a library that emulates a control from a different platform would be to use what is already built into the Android SDK.  `PopupWindow` ([docs links](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)) would allow you to provide this same functionality and properly anchor the content to the `EditText` view.  It can be passed a content view just like an activity or dialog, so the API is more consistent.

When you display a `PopupWindow` with `showAsDropDown()`, the framework will maintain the anchor position to the supplied view when operations like scrolling occur.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I implemented PopupWindow, but it has problems of its own when it comes to positioning the popup with longer content - it cuts the content off, rather than positioning it above the source view, and there's no way to specify that you want the popup to appear.   

I've not marked this as accepted answer because it hasn't tackled the initial question, but rather provided a workaround.

Comment: A PopupWindow won't automatically scroll content any more than an Activity or Fragment would.  You would need to add a ScrollView in your content.  You would likely need to control the PopupWindow size to be fixed at a certain point in order to better control the anchor locations.  PopupWindow gives you all the tools, it's up to you to write a little code.

Comment: I'm using it in a scrollview - what is happening is that if the anchorview is far enough down the scrollview, and the popupwindow is sufficiently long, and the keyboard is dismissed, then the popupwindow is truncated, rather than repositioning above the anchorview. I see in API 19 there is an extra parameter, _gravity_ which I assume was factored in to deal with this situation.

Comment: BTW, are you familiar with `TextView.setError()`?  Your use case might just be simple enough to use that (from what I understand of it). https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError(java.lang.CharSequence)